# Latest XAMPP Server :: use mysql_connect() or mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP Server for about 5 Years almost.

As you know that after `mysqli` , the XAMPP Versions Comment out the `extension=php_mysql.dll` in *php.ini* File.

But Still we can use mysql functions by Un-commenting `extension=php_mysql.dll` in *php.ini* File.

Problem is:

> But Now, The Newly Latest Version of XAMPP Server removed extension=php_mysql.dll from php.ini File.

So Kindly tell me how can I use mysql functions now?

Comment: simple don't use it. go for `mysqli_*` Or `PDO` libraries which are provided. More efficient and able to handle `SQL Injection` perfectly. Easiy to learn also. [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)  and  [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: I know Bro, but most of the PHP Projects that are available on internet used mysql functions. So what should we do to run them ?

Comment: then install that `.dll` file and add that extension in your `php.ini` file and restart your server.

Comment: The problem will still exist Bro. Because by downloading only php_mysql.dll will not work but there are lots of other files needed to execute it but i want accurate and working solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to access the server, right? Modify your connection file and instead of putting localhost put your ip address you can check in cmd with the ipconfig command I hope you have succeeded in your question. good luck.

Comment: Bro, Learn English First :P.